# rbind matrices from a list of a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a `list` of a `list` of matrices. Each `list` has the same number of `matrices` where each `matrix` has the same number of columns:

```
set.seed(1)

mat.lol <- list(list1=list(matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(200),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(140),ncol=10)),
                list2=list(matrix(rnorm(80),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(220),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(110),ncol=10)),
                list3=list(matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(500),ncol=10),matrix(rnorm(650),ncol=10)))
```

And I'd like to `rbind` each `matrix` `i` across all lists so that I end up with this `list` of `matrices`:

```
mat.list <- list(rbind(mat.lol[[1]][[1]],mat.lol[[2]][[1]],mat.lol[[3]][[1]]),
                 rbind(mat.lol[[1]][[2]],mat.lol[[2]][[2]],mat.lol[[3]][[2]]),
                 rbind(mat.lol[[1]][[3]],mat.lol[[2]][[3]],mat.lol[[3]][[3]]))
```

What would be the `apply` `function` that achieves that?

Comment: `lapply(mat.lol, function(x) Reduce(rbind,x))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transpose()` function from `purrr` package to *turn the list inside out* so that each sub list contains all the matrices you want to bind together, and then you can simply loop through the result list and `rbind` the matrices:

```
library(purrr)
mat.list.1 <- lapply(transpose(mat.lol), do.call, what=rbind)

identical(mat.list, mat.list.1)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

To stick with `purrr` syntax:

```
mat.list.3 <- transpose(mat.lol) %>% map(do.call, what=rbind)

identical(mat.list, mat.list.3)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Or you can use `Map` from base R:

```
mat.list.2 <- do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, mat.lol))

identical(mat.list, mat.list.2)
# [1] TRUE
```